# HTML/CSS paragraph breaks, keep <p> entirely with or without floated image

Tags: html, css

I have a floated section of image/text:

```
<div>
  <img style="margin: 0 10 10 10;float: left;" src="img/index.png"/>
  <p>...<br/>...</p>
  <p>...<br/>...</p>
  ...
</div>
```

The first <p> is correctly alongside the image. Depending on <p> qty/lengths, image & screen size subsequent <p>'s may - or may not - 'fit' (in their entirety) alongside the image.

I'm seeking a solution (pref. css based) whereby any <p> (beyond the first) that won't fit entirely alongside the image is placed below it (ie. excepting the first, <p>'s do not 'break' to start wrapping below the image 'part way through').

Comment: That's the nature of floats... You can use `clear: left` (or `both`) on the paragraphs which you want to move below the floated image, but I don't think there's any way to automatically get the result you describe.

Comment: :( aware of 'clear' but - as you rightly say - couldn't see any way of applying them to resolve this case.